# Java - Could not find the main class

Tags: java

When I try to run a simple Hello World program I keep getting a message saying `Could not find the main class`.

I found [this thread on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1163850) which suggested that my `CLASSPATH` variable is messed up, but I couldn't find a way to fix it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post your code, its the only way. This is a bit out of scope since its not a problem with Ubuntu it self but give it a go.

Comment: @BrunoPereira this is a problem with Ubuntu. Why does it behave differently than MacOSX and Windows? I created a shell script with the gradle application plugin, and my paths are correct.

Comment: I would suggest looking into gradle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the code looks like:

```
class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

you need to run `java Foo` in the directory containing `Foo.class` (after compiling with `javac Foo.java`). If you're in a different directory, say `~` where the class file is located at `~/bar/Foo.class`, you need to set the classpath before running java:

```
CLASSPATH=~/bar java Foo
```

If you're using packages, e.g.:

```
package bar;
class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

then you need to save it to `path/bar/Foo.java` and compile `path/bar/Foo.class` with `javac path/bar/Foo.java` and run from `path/`:

```
java bar.Foo
```

Comment: Thanks it Worked! Btw is there any way to make it so that I can run java ~/bar/foo without setting the class path first? Either way thank you very much.

Comment: Does `java -cp ~/bar foo` count? `-cp` is the short option for `-classpath` and is the same as setting `CLASSPATH`

Comment: Couple comments: first, a strong recommendation to avoid the env var $CLASSPATH like the plague; second, a gentle suggestion to avoid shell-specific expansions, like assuming "~" will evaluate to $HOME. E.g, this works (because "~" expands before Java is run): CLASSPATH=~/tmp java bar.Foo; as does this: java -cp ~/tmp bar.Foo; but this does not (added quotes): java -cp "~/cp" bar.Foo ... but this does work: java -cp "$HOME/bar" ... All these of course have nothing to do with Java, but rather shell quirks, where quotes (or the absence thereof) can cause unexpected results for the uninitiated...