# JAR Issue: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, jar

I have a Java software that run perfectly in Windows.

The folder structure is:

```
-dist
   - lib
   - PowerHarvestingConfFx.jar
```

But when I try to open in Ubuntu I get this error:

```
cd dist
java -jar ./PowerHarvestingConfFx.jar 
Error: Could not find or load main class powerharvestingconffx.PowerHarvestingConfFx
```

What kind of problem could be?

Comment: The answer here may point you in the right direction.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/77608/java-could-not-find-the-main-class